# Ordenar vetor de Char em C utilizando método de seleção

Tags: c, classificação, char

Estou tentando ordenar um vetor de char utilizando o método de seleção(Seletion Sort), porém ele está me retornando o vetor exatamente do mesmo jeito, sem fazer uma troca sequer. Alguém pode me apontar onde está o erro no código?

```
void selectionSortChar(char v[][30], int max) {
    int i, j, min;
    char aux[30];

    for (i = 0; i < (max - 1); i++) {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < max; j++) {
            if (stricmp(v[j], v[j + 1]) > 0) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != min) {
            strcpy(aux, v[j]);
            strcpy(v[j], v[j + 1]);
            strcpy(v[j + 1], aux);
        }
    }
    mostraVetorChar(v, 6);
}
```

Comment: Eu não testei, nem sei onde está o erro, mas olhando rapidinho, o último `if` não deveria ser min ao invés de j não?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nessa linha:

```
if (stricmp(v[j], v[j + 1]) > 0) {
```

Você está comparando `j` com `j + 1`, e não com `min`. Inclusive isso pode causar um *segfault*, pois `j + 1` pode ser igual a `max`! (assumindo que `max` é o limite exclusivo)

Assumindo que você pretende ordenar em ordem decrescente (caso contrário, é só inverter a comparação de `>` para `<`), substitua essa linha problemática por:

```
if (strcmp(v[min], v[j]) > 0) {
```

E eu acredito que tudo vai funcionar corretamente. Se `max` for um limite **inclusivo**, também é necessário mudar as condições de ambos os `for`s para `<=`.

**Atualização:** conforme [apontado por Felipe Avelar nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55073/ordenar-vetor-de-char-em-c-utilizando-m%C3%A9todo-de-sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o/55076#comment113006_55073), dentro do último `if` você também está permutando `j` com `j + 1`, e não `i` com `min`. Troque esse último `if` para:

```
if (i != min) {
    strcpy(aux, v[i]);
    strcpy(v[i], v[min]);
    strcpy(v[min], aux);
}
```

Comment: mgibsonbr, ba não tinha visto isso, erro bem bobo mesmo. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!